# Visual Studio For Mac .net Core 2.0 Ajax passing model to controller

Tags: c#, ajax, macos, http-post

I'm trying to make a `POST` request to my controller with passing model from client side using Ajax.

My controller is

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetMobiles(Model Datas)
{
    string url = "http://mobilws.infomobil.com.tr/mobilws/services/mobiles?token=" + Datas.Token;
    string result = string.Empty;

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

My Model.cs is

```
public class Model
{
  public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

And ajax is

```
var model = { Token: Token };

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../Home/GetMobiles',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ Datas: model }),
    success: function (data)
    {
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) { 
        alert(errMsg); 
    }
});
```

But when I start a debugging session, the bound model is always null.

Do you have any idea to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community @muratgoller.

The problem, I imagine, has to the with the way you're passing the data. The [model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.0) is failing to succeed because you assign the model to the `Datas` property.

Instead, pass the serialized model **directly** in your ajax call.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../Home/GetMobiles',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    success: function (data)
    {
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) { 
        alert(errMsg); 
    }
});
```

In order for your JSON to be [interpreted by the model binder](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/)  the `Controller` side. You will likely need to add the `[FromBody]` hint to the action.

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetMobiles([FromBody]Model Datas)
{
    //rest of code
}
```